# Launch Flow in Modal - pass variable

Tags: visual-workflow, json, modal, variable

I am Using AppExchange Launch Flow in Modal. I can't manage to figure out the proper syntax to pass the value of a variable field to my flow input variable string.  I am adding the Modal button to my Opportunity detail page using Lightning App Builder.

I got the record id by using the following syntax:

```
"name" : "varOpportunityId", "type" : "String", "value": "_RECORDID_"
```

but I also need to pass the Opportunity Description field to my flow.  I have tried the following without success:

```
"name" : "varWOFieldMessage", "type" : "Text", "value": "{!$Label.Description}" 
"name" : "varWOFieldMessage", "type" : "Text", "value": "{!Description}" 
"name" : "varWOFieldMessage", "type" : "Text", "value": "{!Opportunity.Description}"
```

Appreciate the help from anyone.  I've spent hours trying to get this working.

Thanks.

Comment: That should say _RECORDID_

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). You can [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358838/edit) your question (look in the bottom left of your question for the "Edit" link) to make changes and add updates and more information, rather than adding that in the comments. Additional information in comments is often overlooked by potential helpers/answerers.